# Getting occasional access to industrial linux server for personal research hobbying

Tags: hosting

How can I get access to a industrial/research server? Occasional use and root/install access would be great. I would love to have 100GB+ memory on demand available occasionally. Web services seems expensive and aimed at hosting.

Comment: This is probably not suited here, buy this is nowadays known as cloud/computing providers, or any simmilar cloud-related terms. Try any of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cloud_computing_providers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cheap and easy access to 100GB of memory will make you a sloppy coder.  If you've a valid reason to require such a vast quantity of memory, I'd love to hear it.  The trend for server scaling is more out, rather than up, so you'd do well to look into map-reduce technologies, so you can use a cluster of cheap servers, rather than one big one.

Don't know what you mean by "industrial" linux server, other than "somebody else's server" - And unless you're very good friends with them, they'll probably not give you access.  I sure as hell wouldn't.

If you *really* want a huge server to play with now and again, I suggest you take a look at the

```
High Memory Cluster Eight Extra Large Instance

244 GiB of memory
88 EC2 Compute Units (2 x Intel Xeon E5-2670, eight-core. Intel Turbo, NUMA)*
240 GB of SSD instance storage
64-bit platform
I/O Performance: Very High (10 Gigabit Ethernet)
EBS-Optimized Available: No
API name: cr1.8xlarge
```

Instance on Amazon EC2.  A snip at $3.5/hour.  Not bad if you only need 2-3 hours usage, as if they're stopped, you don't pay.

Or if you've got the money, there's this. 
[image: immense server]

Comment: Thanks! Re: "make you a sloppy coder" and "somebody else's server". Yes! That's exactly what I want! I want to assess and price the cost of paying somebody else to manage the server, backups and share my sloppy one-off experimental needs with a pool of other sloppy, ingrates. The 100GB limit is hypothetical, but I'm trying to post some number that is bigger than what is typically achievable on a home setup. Do I __need__ such things? Probably not. I can usually work around memory limits by spending *time* working with the code and data.

Comment: 100GB isn't *that* far beyond the realms of home/research affordability.  A 100GB RAM server from broadberry would come in at just less than £2,000.  Or so.

Comment: It's expensive, but not the £15,000 it used to be.

Comment: Haha, just saw the cyberserve edit. I'll take two! I think amazon instances are probably a good deal for a few hours a week of fooling with data.

Comment: Couldn't resist posting that ;)